# Yajilin minicubes: the Hullabaloo, the Brouhaha, the Bangarang

Tags: grid-deduction, three-dimensional

> These are three-dimensional yajilin puzzles. In each puzzle, the four squares depict the layers of a $4\times4\times4$ cube.
>
> - Shade some cells on each layer. The numbered cells show how many shaded cells (not includong numbered cells) are in the direction of the arrow.
> - Some numbers have been replaced with question marks to make the puzzle more difficult. Cells with question marks behave the same as other numbered cells.
> - Diagonal arrows point to squares on other layers. An up-left arrow points to smaller-numbered layers, and a down-right arrow points at higher-numbered layers. For example, a down-right arrow on layer 2 points to cells in the same row and same column on layers 3 and 4.
> - Shaded cells cannot be adjacent to another shaded cell (even those on different levels). The shaded cells are allowed to touch the numbered cells, however.
> - Unshaded unnumbered cells on each layer are all adjacent to one another in 2D (i.e. each layer is treated separately).
> - Make a single loop in 3D space which goes through every unshaded, unnumbered cell.
>
> [image]

Comment: What is a '?' ?

Comment: Oops, that was missing from the description. Added now, sorry about that.

Comment: "Unshaded cells on each layer are all connected in 2D (i.e. each layer is treated separately)." does that include numbered cells?

Comment: "The numbered cells show how many shaded cells are in the direction of the arrow." - does that include numbered cells, or only user-shaded cells?

Comment: @OmegaKrypton No, only user-unshaded cells.

Comment: @Birjolaxew No, only user-shaded cells.

Comment: Clarified both points in the rules.

Comment: "Unshaded unnumbered cells on each layer are all connected in 2D" - I assume this means that there are two separate groups of connected cells in each central layer (#2 and #3) in 2D, since these layers must have four cells in total that go in/out (all 4 cannot be connected by the same line in 2D, since the line leaves the 2D plane in all 4 of these cells and a line only has 2 ends)

Comment: @Birjolaxew The unshaded cells are all connected to each other by placement, they do not have to be connected by a line. The line can leave and enter a layer as often as it wants.

Comment: @wl Hmm let me check...

Comment: @wl Sure, feel free to post both versions.

Comment: Yeah, looks like you're right. I should really record the steps instead of just the final solution when making these... I'll make an edit soon to fix this.

Comment: Added two zeroes to the first layer. That should fix it...

Comment: Is it correct that a *loop* here is an embedded circle? Rot13(Fb gung, sbe vafgnapr, gur gbc-yrsg fdhner va ynlre 6 bs gur svefg chmmyr unf gb or funqrq rira gubhtu ab ahzore cbvagf va gung qverpgvba, orpnhfr ab ybbc pbhyq cbffvoyl tb guebhtu gurer?)

Comment: @ArnaudMortier It is certainly allowed to add shaded cells in places where the numbers by themselves don't require it. For example, the solution to Nikoli's [example puzzle](http://www.nikoli.co.jp/en/puzzles/yajilin.html) contains two shaded cells which don't have any arrows pointing to them. Does that answer the question?

Comment: Thanks for confirming that. The question was more about whether the way I arrived at that conclusion was a correct interpretation of the word "loop". But I guess that the answer is yes then.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a [pencil-and-paper-games](/questions/tagged/pencil-and-paper-games) full solution... yay

> [image]

Comment: Pen and paper is a good strategy for this +1.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the answer to the first one at least (apologies for the crude drawing)

> [image]